# Crashplan headless suppport: .ui_info resets every time I reboot

Tags: macos, backup

I've recently updated to CrashPlan 4.3.0 on my mac running OS X 10.10.3.

I've followed the headless guide on the CrashPlan support site and contacted their support line, whom are usually good but this time refused to help me because headless CrashPlan an unsupported config.

Every time I reboot my OS X 10.10.4 machine I find that /Library/Application\ Support/CrashPlan/.ui_info file defaults to it's normal local CrashPlan server details. Ie. back to 4243,hashed token.

No matter how many times I change it to match '4200,crashplan server token from my linux server' it defaults back.

Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. After googling for a while I found what Code42 (CrashPlan's developers) state in their instructions for [running CrashPlan on a headless computer](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Using_CrashPlan_On_A_Headless_Computer):

> **Changes Can Be Reset**
>
> The changes made in this step are reset when the CrashPlan service on the local computer restarts. To avoid overwriting your changes, leave the CrashPlan service running on your local computer.

Comment: I think in the end I made the file immutable as mentioned in the followin reddit post.

https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/3bszem/anyone_having_issues_connecting_to_the_crashplan/

If the issue persists, try setting the file as immutable so that it cannot be modified:
sudo chflags schg /Library/Application\ Support/CrashPlan/.ui_info

Answer (score 0):

Found the same problem myself.  PITA, however I changed the file (c:\programdata\crashplan\.ui_info) to read only and it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: It would be nice if people who downvoted added a comment to say why.  It would appear that this answer is the same as the selected answer (but for being Windows).  So why the downvote?